# Syntax changes between Swift 2.2 and 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, swift3

I am in the process of converting a C program to Swift.  I have an unsigned int 8 bit array of 64 elements, which I can write in Swift3 as:

```
let BLAKE2B_KEYBYTES = 64
var mem = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: BLAKE2B_KEYBYTES)
```

Swift 2.2, however, requires this:

```
let BLAKE2B_KEYBYTES = 64
var mem = [UInt8](count: BLAKE2B_KEYBYTES, repeatedValue: 0)
```

so, keywords are different and position is important, since count MUST precede repeatedValue in 2.2, but repeating must precede count in 3.

The online docs are quite sketchy on these issues.  What I am unable to locate is a definitive document on Swift 2.2 syntax.  If anyone can point me to the TRUTH on Swift 2.2, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Array Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Array/s:FSacFT5countSi13repeatedValuex_GSax_) (Swift 2.2) which has the initializer syntax. You can also ⌘-click on the word Array in your code to jump to the Array interface/definition.

The source of ultimate truth, for Swift 3 and beyond, is the Array implementation in the standard library: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L510-L520